# How to use streams for terminating loop over collection conditionally

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How to use streams to achieve something like what the following code snippet shows ?
Basically, I need to terminate a loop returning one value based on a condition, or returning another value again, based on a condition.

```
enum Day {
  SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY
} 

class MyObj {
  Day d;
  public Day getDay();
}

List<MyObj> myObjList;

Day Myfunc () {
// If atleast one obj belongs to SUNDAY or MONDAY, return.
Day myDay = null;
for(MyObj myObj : myObjList) {
  if(myObj.getDay() == Day.SUNDAY || myObj.getDay() == Day.MONDAY) {
    return myObj.getDay();
  }
  else if (myObj.getDay() == Day.TUESDAY) {
    myDay = myObj.getDay();
  }
 }
return myDay;
}
```

Comment: you can use brake to stop the loop condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand the logic of your function as the following:

1. If there's SUNDAY or MONDAY in the input, return the first one of them.
2. Otherwise if there's TUESDAY, return it.
3. Otherwise return null.

You can implement this logic in the Java-8 style iterating the list twice and using `Optional.orElseGet`:

```
myObjList.stream().map(MyObj::getDay).filter(d -> d == Day.SUNDAY || d == Day.MONDAY)
    .findFirst()
    .orElseGet(() -> myObjList
        .stream().map(MyObj::getDay).anyMatch(d -> d == Day.TUESDAY) ? Day.TUESDAY : null);
```

Looks kinda ugly, so better to stick with the original imperative code.

---

An alternative one-pass solution would be to introduce the days priority and use it:

```
int priority(Day d) {
    switch(d) {
    case SUNDAY:
    case MONDAY:
        return 10; // max priority
    case TUESDAY:
        return 5;
    default:
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now you can use `Stream.max`:

```
return myObjList.stream().map(MyObj::getDay).max(Comparator.comparingInt(this::priority))
        .filter(day -> priority(day) > 0).orElse(null);
```

Though it's longer than original code, such solution looks more flexible: you can easily add more cases tweaking the `priority` method.

Comment: Ok, I was looking for something like "orElseGet()". Thanks.

Like you said, I too think original code looks more cleaner.

Comment: but OP wants details of last occured `Tusesday` not the first occured and I think `anyMatch()` would give you the details of first  occured `Tuesday`

Comment: I think we'll have to iterate the list twice, if we want to use streams. Rather, using old style for loop is more efficient.

Comment: @singhakash, it's enum, so the last occured Tuesday is indistinguishable from the first occured Tuesday.

Comment: @TagirValeev I am not taking about enum I am saying the code OP posted returns the last element of list where the `Tuesday` matches but your solution give the first element if the list which matches Tuesday what it has to do with enum

Comment: @singhakash, the code returns not the original list element (of `MyObj` type), but the `Day` enum value. Look at it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stream like this:

```
list.stream().filter(myObj -> myObj.getDay() == Day.SUNDAY || myObj.getDay() == Day.MONDAY);
```

And also for terminating the `return` it self can terminate the loop.

Comment: But, I need to terminate the loop if Sunday or Monday, in one way, and if Tuesday, in another way. So, I'm looking for some if-else-if kind of logic using streams.

Comment: Then you have already added the word `return` it can terminate the loop, no need to do extra code for that